# VaryByParam not working with parameter, only *

Tags: ajax, json, model-view-controller, outputcache

I've taken a look at the other VaryByParam questions, but I haven't been able to find the answer to my question.  I have an MVC site that has the following action defined:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "TargetID")]
public JsonResult IsThingAllowed(int TargetID)
{
    bool isAllowed = IsAllowed(TargetID);

    return Json(isAllowed, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

No matter what comes in for TargetID, the cached value gets returned.  However, if I change `TargetID` to be `*`, it works as expected (cached values vary by `TargetID`):

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

Here's the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/MyController/IsThingAllowed",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "TargetID": id }), // This is definitely varying!
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

        updateThing(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {

    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong when the parameter is explicitly named?

**EDIT:**  Works if we use `GET` instead of `POST`..  but `POST` obviously **works**, since it works when we use `*`.

Here's it working with `GET`:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "/MyController/IsThingAllowed",
     type: "GET",
     data: { TargetID: id },
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

         updateThing(data);
     },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {

     }
 });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data: {TargetID: myTargetID},`?

Comment: @IliaG:  `myTargetID` is `var myTargetID = JSON.stringify({ "TargetID": id });` - I'll update the question for clarity.

Comment: but... not it is `CorrespondentID`? :)

Comment: @IliaG:  Fixed.  Sanitizing for web.  (Removing domain information.)

Comment: I am still confused... why are you passing stringified version to the `data`? This is basically the body of you request. It should be URL encoded, not JSON encoded. In either case `VaryByParam` would only apply to GET or POST parameter, not a field in a JSON structure.

Comment: Then what makes it work when using `GET` or using `*` with `POST`?  (In reply to your first question - I'm fixing a bug; didn't write the initial code.)

Comment: @IliaG:  Although, for `GET` to work, I did have to switch to JSON structure instead of stringifying it.  (Updated question with relevant change.)

Comment: make sure you change your `contentType`. Remove it to default to url-encoded.

Comment: @IliaG: Thanks; that seems to allow the client (browser) to cache the return value, so fewer trips to the server.